# Customize width of pinned tabs in firefox using Tab Mix Plus

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, browser-tabs

I use [Tab Mix Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-mix-plus/) to give my Firefox tabs more customizability.  I love pinned tabs, but they are so small that they can be somewhat hard to click, especially on a touchscreen.  **Is it possible to customize the width of pinned tabs?**  I played around with the settings of Tab Mix Plus, but there doesn't appear to be anything there.

The solution doesn't necessarily have to use Tab Mix Plus, but I'd prefer it.

Note:  I've considered using a solution other than pinning tabs (e.g., protecting tabs), but I like the way pinned tabs automatically move to the left side, and how if I open so many tabs so that the tab rows scroll down, the pinned tabs are always on the left side of the highest visible row.

---

Clarification on the scrolling behavior mentioned in the last line:  I limit the minimum width of my tabs, and if I open too many tabs for one row, Tab Mix Plus displays them in a second row, then a third row.  I've set the maximum number of rows to three, so if I open more tabs than can fit on three rows, a fourth row opens -- but there are only three rows displayed at a time, with a scrollbar to scroll vertically between them.  The essential behavior of pinned tabs is that pinned tabs always show up in the top visible row, even if the true top rows is hidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Is it possible to customize the width of Firefox pinned tabs?

Yes. This can be done with a custom style.

1. Download and install the [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/) extension.
2. Click on the Stylish icon.
3. Click on "Manage styles"

   > [image]
4. Click on "Write New Style."
5. Give the Style a "Name", for example `PinnedTabWidth`.
6. Add the following code (adjust the `width` value to your taste):

   ```
   @namespace url(http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul);

   .tabbrowser-tab[pinned] {
     width: 82px;
   }
   ```
7. Click "Save".

   > [image]

Source [How to change Firefox pinned tab width](http://www.nabakumar.com/2013/09/how-to-change-firefox-pinned-tab-width.html)

Comment: I'm new to this community -- in the SE community with which I am most familiar (mathematica.SE), it's considered best practice to wait 24 hours before accepting an answer.  Is that not the case here?

Comment: @jjc385 It's fine if you want to wait 24 hrs. We don't really do that here as you can always change your accept if a better answer comes along. But I don't think you will get a better answer ... ;p

Comment: Unfortunately this no longer works (at least for me), presumably coinciding with Stylish's update beyond legacy status.  Pinned tabs are now displayed with their default width.

Comment: @jjc385 You can use https://add0n.com/stylus.html instead (replacement for Stylish)

Comment: Hmm, I'm still having the same problem with Stylus.  (Thanks for the speedy reply.)